# Make a Div fill the width of content not just the screen

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to fix this div. It is set to 100% width yet it doesn't take up the whole page. What can I do to fix this?

[image: picture]

Relevant code (some things I was messing with are still in the code):

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="position: page; top: 0; left: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%;">
        <div id="header" style="height: 50px; width: 100%; position:relative; background-color: #2A333E;">
            <div style="height: 50px;">
                <img alt="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/hRaRJhq.png" style="width: 157px; height: 52px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</form>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: style="position: page; -snip-" ?

Comment: I get 100% with with your snippet.

Comment: code you posted works fine https://jsfiddle.net/9tpn2L5g/

Comment: @PascalClaes Well what could be interfering with this? Because it only fills my screen view, not the actual content of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that 100% is calculated on viewport, not on page content, if you don't need to scroll horizontally your navbar you can just set position of navbar to fixed and add some top padding to body to not cover content above.

But if you want navbar to be scrolled with content then you must place it in the same container where this table is.

Answer (score 0):

Your logo is transparent and has a min width.
So when the page becomes too narrow, the background color from the logo overwrites the header background color.

Add the background color to your image tag.

```
<img alt="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/hRaRJhq.png" style="width: 157px; height: 52px; background-color: #2A333E" />
```